# Can media ask a non profit organization for financial informations? (Canada)

Tags: canada

I work as a VP finance for a non profit organization in New Brunswick, Canada and last week a journal contacted us for financial informations.

I know there is a Right to Information and Protection of Privacy Act (RTIPPA) in Canada but after reading it im not sure we are a public body as described in the act. Can somebody tell me if my organization is under a law that would enable requests to get access to our financial informations?

Comment: Ask a lawyer. Stack Exchange cannot provide specific legal advice.

Comment: Maybe you can strip out the personal aspects and ask a more general question about nonprofits and RTIPPA...

Comment: we would love to assist you, but answering this question would be giving legal advice. Please generalize per Pat. W's comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The law is a bit murky because it doesn't define "public body", but to compensate, the NB government promulgates a list of [things it thinks are public bodies](http://www2.gnb.ca/content/dam/gnb/Departments/gs-sg/pdf/DirectoryofPublicBodies.pdf). A more intuitive expression would be "government agency". Anyhow, you can see if your name and address are on the list, because it is quite specific.